# Why does overflow-x add padding to my divs?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a setup where I have a `block`-display `div` containing `inline-block`-display `div`s in a horizontal fashion. However, if the screen is narrow, I don't want text overflowing in each `div` as to disrupt the `div` to its right.

However, when I add `overflow-x: hidden` to my `inline-block`s, it adds padding to the bottom of the `block` `div`.

[image: Result of HTML/CSS]

Notice how in the top row, the grey box extends below the darker boxes, while in the bottom, they line up? The *only* difference is that the second row does not have an `overflow-x` attribute set.

I have tested this on Chrome 39, Chrome 40, and IE 11. It seems to be desired behavior, but I don't want it. I also don't want to have to set a strict height on the `div`s.

**Why is this padding added when using `overflow`, and how do I get rid of it?**

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y4t29uwj/1/)

## Actual code

### HTML

```
<div id="row1">
    <div class="cell">AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
    <div class="cell">BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</div>
    <div class="cell">CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</div>
</div>
<br/><br/>
<div id="row2">
    <div class="cell">AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
    <div class="cell">BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</div>
    <div class="cell">CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
#row1, #row2 {
    background: #ddd;
    width: 100%;
}

.cell {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #bbb;
    padding: 6px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 30%;
}

#row1 .cell {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [CSS 2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align):

> The baseline of an 'inline-block' is the baseline of its last line box
>   in the normal flow, unless it has either no in-flow line boxes or if
>   its 'overflow' property has a computed value other than 'visible', in
>   which case the baseline is the bottom margin edge.

So when you add `overflow-x:hidden`, `overflow`, which is a shorthand property for `overflow-x` and `overflow-y`, no longer has a computed value of 'visible'. So the inline-blocks change from having their baselines given by their inner line boxes, to their baselines being their bottom margin edges.

That means that the bottom margin edges align with the baseline of the [strut](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#strut) of the line-box in which the inline-block elements sit, which means that the line box must be increased in height to allow space for the descender of the strut.

You can eliminate the problem by setting the `vertical-align` of the inline-boxes to `top`so that their bottoms do not have to align with the baseline of the strut, and the strut will move up to not take any extra room in the line box.

See http://jsfiddle.net/y4t29uwj/2/

Answer (score 0):

Weird... I don't know why it behaves like that. If it can help you:

- On Safari Mac, no padding is added.
- Adding `line-height: 0.5;` to `#row1, #row2 {...}` removed the padding for me on Chrome Mac.